# How can I open a window and select objects in that window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
newWindow=window.open(document.URL);
$('div#header',newWindow.document).hide();
$('div#footer',newWindow.document).hide();
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.  Any ideas?

Comment: is the new window running under the same document.domain?

Comment: @jbabey, the new window loads `document.URL`.

Comment: Unfortunately jQuery's `.ready` function only works in the context of the current window, so you'll have to wait for `.load` on the new window or create your own implementation of `.ready` that can work across window contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
newWindow = window.open(document.URL);
$(newWindow).load(function() {
    $('#header', newWindow.document).hide();
    $('#footer', newWindow.document).hide();
});
```

Comment: For those who want to test, press ctrl+shift+j (google chrome) on this page and copypaste. You should get this page without footer and header